# Неожиданный символ после shape

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Код:

```
 class Article extends React.Component{
  propTypes: {
    data: React.PropTypes.shape({
      author: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      text:  React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      bigText:  React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      date:  React.PropTypes.number.isRequired
    })
  }
  render(){
    var author = this.props.data.author,
    text = this.props.data.text,
    bigText = this.props.data.bigText,
    date = this.props.data.date    ;
    return(
      <div className='article'>
      <p className ="name text">{text}</p>
      <p className='name author'>{author}</p>
      <p className = 'name bigText'>{bigText}</p>
      <p className = 'name date'>{date}</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
};
```

Консоль:

```
      21 |class Article extends React.Component{
      22 |   propTypes: {
    > 23 |      data: React.PropTypes.shape({
         |                                 ^
      24 |        author: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      25 |        text: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      26 |        bigText: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
```

Изучаю react, в учебнике есть пример с shape, но в браузере он не работает.

Comment: Это похоже на сообщение об ошибке и неплохо бы увидеть эту ошибку

Comment: Это и есть ошибка. Точнее кусок из консоли

Comment: Хм. Это какой-то странный несуществующий синтаксис. Что за учебник такой?

Возможно где-то в начале этого учебника есть что-то про транспиляцию

Comment: Обычный учебник. Старый просто. Но в доках на оф. сайте точно такой же синтаксис.

Comment: Должно быть примерно так: `static propTypes = { ... }`. Впрочем этот синтаксис всё равно ещё не стандартизирован и вам нужен babel для транспилирования этого кода в код понятный браузерам.

Comment: Ну и дайте ссылку на сайт, что ли

Comment: Это помесь двух синтаксисов: синтаксиса классов и синтаксиса где в React.createClass пробрасывается объект, одним из свойств которого является propTypes. Помесь сделана методом творческой копипасты видимо, и является нежизнеспособной химерой, о чем консоль вам и говорит.